# Dot net core scaffolding failed while adding controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am totally new to dot net core and know C# a little. I was trying to go through this [microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) to learn the implementation.

When I tried to use scaffolding to add the controller I got following error:

[image]

I think I should go ahead and check this file but not able to find it as well. Did my part of internet search but no luck so far.

Even a little help would be appreciated. Thanks.

This is my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Cloud you please share more detailed info, like the values in the form before scaffolding the code. Also your model? Can your project be built?

Comment: Which version of asp.net core and vs do you use?Could you show your csproj file?

Comment: @XingZou: Thanks for response, I am using VS2019 and asp.net core 3.0.101. I will add the csproj file as well.

Comment: It works well using your csproj file,the tutorial is no problem.I suggest that you could check your error list and check your code wherever  JSON is used.Or could you create a brand new web api to test the problem?

Comment: @XingZou: Well I can try to build another version :) and the error is already posted in the screenshot.

Comment: Could you please share your scaffolding code, there may be some characters that cause errors.

Comment: @XingZou Tried to create a new solution for webapi and also for mvc application using dot net core, but got the error during scaffolding in both of them as well. Maybe something is wrong with my dotnet version (3.0.101).

Comment: I have also tried with [asp.net core sdk 3.0.101](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) and it also works, make sure vs version is v16.3 or later.maybe you could ask your problem on github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues) if you still have problems.

Comment: Sure @XingZou, I will post it there. Meanwhile if you could find the reason for this please don't forget to update. :)